# mySQL select maximum value for column A with same values in column B

Tags: mysql

Here's the table in question, generated from the command at the bottom of this question:

```
+--------------+-----------------+
| usr_postcode | pdp_point_total |
+--------------+-----------------+
| MS2 8LA      |             160 |
| MS2 8LA      |             140 |
| MS2 8LA      |             110 |
| MS2 8LA      |             100 |
| MS2 8LA      |              90 |
| MS2 8LA      |              80 |
| MS2 8LA      |              50 |
| MS2 8LA      |              30 |
| WN4 9NV      |              25 |
| MS2 8LA      |              20 |
| SL6 1SR      |              10 |
| SL1 4DX      |              10 |
+--------------+-----------------+
```

I'd like to find the largest value in the second column for each value in column one, so the output would be something like:

```
-------------
MS2 8LA | 160
WN4 9NV | 25
SL6 1SR | 10
SL1 4DX | 10
-------------
```

the two columns are from different tables so at the moment this is my command:

```
SELECT DISTINCT users.usr_postcode, point_date_pairs.pdp_point_total FROM users
INNER JOIN point_date_pairs ON users.usr_id_pk = point_date_pairs.usr_id_fk
ORDER BY point_date_pairs.pdp_point_total DESC;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GROUP BY should help:

```
SELECT users.usr_postcode, MAX(point_date_pairs.pdp_point_total)
FROM users
INNER JOIN point_date_pairs ON users.usr_id_pk = point_date_pairs.usr_id_fk
GROUP BY users.usr_postcode ASC
```

Comment: Yes, that works perfectly, thanks! Without the MAX() function, does it just find the first matching pdp_point_total record and show that?

Comment: I'm not sure what the behavior is there, but I wouldn't rely on that because the order of the rows can change. If you use group by you should always use a corresponding aggregate function: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html